# unorderable types: str() > int()

Tags: python, string, int

So the program I am trying to make consists of three inputs equaling a right, isosceles, or an obtuse triangle and when I am running my code, I run into this problem. I already put the int() in front of everything. What am I doing wrong?

```
angle_1 = input("What is the degree of the first angle? ")
angle_2 = input("What is the degree of the second angle? ")
angle_3 = input("What is the degree of the third angle? ")


if int(angle_1 or angle_2 or angle_3) == 90:
    print("This is a right triangle.")
elif int((angle_1 or angle_2 or angle_3) > 90) and int((angle_1 or angle_2 or angle_3) < 180):
    print("This is an obtuse triangle.")
else:
    print("This is an acute triangle.")
```

Comment: You have invented your own syntax, which differs from the interpretation Python uses.  Consider `int(angle_1 or angle_2 or angle_3)`.  This will perform a logical OR of the three angles, then convert the result to an `int`.  Clearly not what you wanted.  So, fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax in your `if` statements are wonky. I would make a list of the angle names, and then loop through them.

```
angle_1 = input("What is the degree of the first angle? ")
angle_2 = input("What is the degree of the second angle? ")
angle_3 = input("What is the degree of the third angle? ")

# This will be looped through
angle_list=[angle_1, angle_2, angle_3] # This will be looped through

for angle in angle_list: # Goes through each inputted angle. 
    if angle == 90:
        print 'This triangle is right.'
        break
    elif angle > 90:
        print 'This triangle is obtuse.'
        break
    else:
        print 'This is an acute triangle.'
        break
```

For future reference, you may want to directly reference the documentation when working with new concepts. `or` is a logical operator, not boolean.

Comment: This isn't right. The list has the literal strings "angle_1" etc... in it, not the values entered by the user. And even if it did, you only check one value at a time and end up printing three things about the angles. Try running it and you'll see.

Comment: @tdelaney right! sorry about that. I think that strings themselves are required for the list (I get a `TypeError` otherwise) but you are absolutely correct about the second point. I will add a `break` in the `for` loop.

Comment: @tdelaney i fixed the first problem--I have to move the list to after the declaration of the variables.

Comment: Problem is still there. `angle_list` is still the string names, you need to remove the quotes to get variable names. The next problem is that you haven't converted the input from string to int, so no matter what, your code will think the triangle is obtuse. Finally, you are only considering the first item in the list (it will always break) so for instance if a user enters 30, 60, 90, the program will see `30` and assume its an acute triangle.

Comment: @tdelaney my apologies, again! i forgot to remove the quotations. But the input is already in `int`, input and not raw_input returns int .

Comment: Original poster is using python 3 where python 2's `raw_input` is now 3's `input` and python 2's `input` (which evaluates the string as a python expression) is removed completely. I didn't notice you were using python 2. Sorry for the confusion! BTW, you may have a python 2 requirement for your classes, but you should really be learing 3. Good luck! (and run your program with 30, 60, 90 - it still needs tweeks).

Comment: ohhhh that makes so much more sense now. thanks for your help @tdelaney!!

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you need to convert input from a string to an int. Nominally, this is done by `val = int(intput('something: '))` but since users have a habit of entering junk, you need to catch errors when you convert. This is a good role for a function.

Your second problem is with the `or` operator as has been described in several places. Thinking of the solution, you have several values that you want to compare, so it would be natural to put them into a list. Once you've done that, python has tricks and helpful functions that will let you ask questions of these values.

Put it all together and you get

```
def get_input(prompt, cast_to=str):
    while True:
        try:
            val = input(prompt)
            return cast_to(val)
        except ValueError:
           print("'{}' is in valid, try againr".format(val))

angle_1 = get_input("What is the degree of the first angle? ", int)
angle_2 = get_input("What is the degree of the second angle? ", int)
angle_3 = get_input("What is the degree of the thrid angle? ", int)

angles = [angle_1, angle_2, angle_3]

if sum(angles) != 180:
    print("We are sticking with Euclidean geometry pal")
elif 90 in angles:
    print("This is a right triangle.")
elif max(angles) > 90:
    print("This is an obtuse triangle.")
else:
    print("This is an acute triangle.")
```